# Is it possible to find a diagonalizable matrix in this situation?

Tags: linear-algebra

let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2&0&0 \\  0&3&-1  \\ 0&-1&3 \end{pmatrix}$

Question:Find an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^TAP$ is a diagonal matrix.

My attempt

I know that $P^T=P^{-1}$

So I can write $P^{-1}AP=D$  where D is a diagonal matrix

Then $A$ is said to be diagonalizable.

But there is a theorem saying that an nxn matrix $A$ is diagonalizable iff A has n linearly independent eigenvectors.

However, I found that the eigenvalues of $A$ are only 2 and 4

I'm confused that if the above is true, then is it solvable?

If yes, where did I get wrong?

Thank you so much for answering my question

Comment: Perhaps either $2$ or $4$ has more than one eigenvector.

Comment: What does that mean?
I get the eigenspace are $span{(0,-1,1)^T}$ and $span{(a,1,1)^T}$ where a is any real number
Then I don't know how to finish the question.

Answer (score 1):

One eigenvector to the eigenvalue $2$ is trivially found: $\vec v_0=(1,0,0)^T$. Now look at the lower blockmatrix only and you'll find another eigenvalue of $2$ with its corresponding eigenvector. This one will be orthogonal to $\vec v_0$...

Comment: So I find those 3 vectors should be $ (1,0,0)^T , (0,1,1)^T and (0,-1,1)^T $

But then what should I do next?

The matrix P is the span of $ (1,0,0)^T , (0,1,1)^T and (0,-1,1)^T $ ? (I find a similar example in my notes)

But after i compute the matrix , I find that $P^T=/=P^{-1}$

Comment: @mathshungry Normalize all your eigenvectors!

Comment: I got the answer, but i don't understand why normalizing the eigenvectors can make me get the required matrix

Comment: @mathshungry $P$ is orthogonal, implying that $P^TP=I$...

Comment: But what does it have to do with normalizing? I'm sorry that I bother you so much

Comment: @math otherwise you don't get 1 on the diagonal,  which is required for $P^T P=I$